# How to get the name of the table from which rows where found

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using a mysql stored procedure that checks if an ID is present in 5-6 tables.
If any of those tables contains that ID, i set a flag to true.
Finally I select the flag using SELECT.

The parameters to the SP are as follows:

```
->settings_type = "branch"
->settings_id (the id that is searched)
```

If the searched ID is present in any of those 6 tables, how can i know from which table the ID was found?

```
BEGIN
DECLARE boolStatus BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

IF settings_type = "branch"
THEN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(tblbatches.intBranchId)   FROM tblbatches         WHERE tblbatches.intBranchId        = settings_id > 0) OR 
         (SELECT COUNT(tblexams.intBranchId)        FROM tblexams           WHERE tblexams.intBranchId      = settings_id > 0) OR
         (SELECT COUNT(tblquestions.intBranchId)    FROM tblquestions   WHERE tblquestions.intBranchId  = settings_id > 0) OR
         (SELECT COUNT(tblresults.intBranchId)  FROM tblresults     WHERE tblresults.intBranchId        = settings_id > 0) OR
         (SELECT COUNT(tblstudents.intBranchId) FROM tblstudents        WHERE tblstudents.intBranchId   = settings_id > 0) OR
         (SELECT COUNT(tblsubjects.intBranchId) FROM tblsubjects        WHERE tblsubjects.intBranchId   = settings_id > 0)
        )
        THEN
            SET boolStatus := TRUE;
    END IF;
    SELECT boolStatus;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Cant you use the JOINS???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to rewrite your procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name(IN settings_type VARCHAR(32), IN settings_id INT)
BEGIN
  IF settings_type = 'branch' THEN
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(total), 0) > 0 status, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(source) source
      FROM
    (
      SELECT 'tblbatches' source, COUNT(*) total
        FROM tblbatches
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tblexams', COUNT(*)
        FROM tblexams 
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tblquestions', COUNT(*) 
        FROM tblquestions 
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tblresults', COUNT(*)
        FROM tblresults
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tblstudents', COUNT(*)
        FROM tblstudents
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tblsubjects', COUNT(*)
        FROM tblsubjects
       WHERE intBranchId = settings_id
    ) q 
     WHERE total > 0;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample output when matching records have been found:

```
| STATUS |                SOURCE |
----------------------------------
|      1 | tblbatches,tblresults |
```

and when they haven't

```
| STATUS | SOURCE |
-------------------
|      0 | (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d7a1/1)** demo

Comment: @user2671915 Did it help? DO you need more help with your question?

Comment: @Biju You're welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.